# kubernetes pod start another while a job is running

Tags: bash, kubernetes

I have a flask api and I am trying to improve it identifying which function calls in the api definition takes the longest time whenever call it. For that I am using a profiler as highlighted in this [repo](https://dev.to/yellalena/profiling-flask-application-to-improve-performance-4970). Whenever I make the api call, this profiler generates a .prof file which I can use with `snakeviz` to visualize.

Now I am trying to run this on aws cluster in the same region where my database is stored to minimize network latency time. I can get the api server running and make the api calls, my question is how can I transfer the `.prof` file from kubernetes pod without disturbing the api server. Is there a way to start a separate shell that transfers file to say an s3 bucket whenever that file is created without killing off the api server.

Comment: You have `kubectl exec` and `kubectl cp`

Answer (score 3):

If you want to automate this process or it's simply hard to figure out connectivity for running `kubectl exec ...`, one idea would be to use [a sidecar container](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/pods/#how-pods-manage-multiple-containers). So your pod contains two containers with a single `emptyDir` volume mounted into both. `emptyDir` is [perhaps the easiest way](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/volumes/#emptydir) to create a folder shared between all containers in a pod.

- First container is your regular Flask API
- Second container is watching for new files in shared folder. Whenever it finds a file there it uploads this file to S3

You will need to configure profiler so it dumps output into a shared folder.
One benefit of this approach is that you don't have to make any major modifications to the existing container running Flask.

Comment: Thank you, `kubectl exec` is sufficient for my usecase, as at the moment I don't need to automate as such. But thanks for your suggestion

Answer (score 1):

The best option the sidecar container.

> Pods that run multiple containers that need to work together. A Pod can encapsulate an application composed of multiple co-located containers that are tightly coupled and need to share resources. These co-located containers form a single cohesive unit of service—for example, one container serving data stored in a shared volume to the public, while a separate sidecar container refreshes or updates those files. The Pod wraps these containers, storage resources, and an ephemeral network identity together as a single unit.

> For example, you might have a container that acts as a web server for files in a shared volume, and a separate "sidecar" container that updates those files from a remote source.

Here's [a link](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/pods/#workload-resources-for-managing-pods)!

The sidecar creation is easy look this:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: demo
spec:
  containers:
  - image: busybox
    command: ["/bin/sh"]
    args: ["-c", "while true; do echo $(date -u) 'Hi I am from Sidecar container'; sleep 5;done"]
    name: sidecar-container
    resources: {}
    volumeMounts:
    - name: var-logs
      mountPath: /var/log
  - image: nginx
    name: main-container
    resources: {}
    ports:
      - containerPort: 80
    volumeMounts:
    - name: var-logs
      mountPath: /usr/share/nginx/html
  dnsPolicy: Default
  volumes:
  - name: var-logs
    emptyDir: {}
```

All you need is change the sidecar container command to your needs.

Comment: Thank you, I was looking `kubectl exec`. It should be sufficient for my use-case as it is only one time thing. But thanks for your suggestion.